# Extract URL from JSON using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have the following json output available and i need to extract the value of href which is the https URL using jq processor.

I have tried using

```
jq -r .links.urn:vodafoneid:follow.hrefs
```

However this does not work ?

JSON Output:

```
{  
   "links":{  
      "urn:somedomainid:follow":{  
         "href":"https://abc.somedomain.com/ula/login?service=IDGW&channel=WEB&usecaseid=a0b51311-d14b-4733-9e6b-ba5f5deec05f&opco=DE&nonce=89e31cde-fecc-41e1-91d6-1f9f84f9c136&acr_values=explicit&scopes=phone_number&returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fidgw.somedomain.com%2Fauthorize%23state%3Da0b51311-d14b-4733-9e6b-ba5f5deec05f",
         "type":"text/html"
      }
   },
   "context":"FOLLOW"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an obvious typo in the field name that you are trying to use `vodafoneid` is not `somedomainid`. But in general to access a field having special characters like `:` in their names, do a proper quoting of the field as below.

```
jq --raw-output '.links."urn:somedomainid:follow".href'
```

[jqplay.org - URL](https://jqplay.org/s/AhaMCazi9o)